# Ipad - my Webview / UIkit safari browser won't run javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, webview

I'm using webview in my xcode javascript refuses to run. has anyone got any ideas why this would happen? could it be that an error in my javascript is blocking it from running? or could it be that javascript has to be setup somehow?

I'm new to ipad dev. Let me know what you need me to post and i will

**Update**

Okay as suggested I made a simple test.

```
<div id="test" style="color:black">sfkjldsf</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write('TEST YOU PIECE OF CRAP');
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
    $('#test').css('background-color','red');
    });
</script>
</body>
```

It shows me a few things. 
1. javascript does actually work
2. the problem lies with loading up jquery
3. if i load jquery locally, ie `src="jquery.js"` it doesn't work. But the document.write command does work.
4. If i load jquery as above from the cdn, it works fine.

My issue is that my ipad won't have internet connectivity so i can't load jquery from the cdn.

Any ideas?

Jason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works, in general, obviously, so something is wrong in your case.

My suggestion is to make a very simple sample/test for yourself, get that working and then build upon it (standard programming strategy for when something doesn't work).

For this simple example, put the javascript right into the html file.  If that works, then likely it's the path to the javascript file that's broken (they are a little odd if I recall correctly).

We'll need more information to help you more. If you make a simple test then it'll be short enough to include.

Comment: Thanks, i've done that and found that the problem is with jquery. take a look at my update

Comment: Several ideas:  1) are you sure it's copying the jquery.js file as part of the copy resources build phase? (did you add it to the project etc).  Open the built app and check.   2) open the jquery.js file and look to see what it tries to include - if it includes other files, it will fail and that might be part of the problem.

Comment: HI, okay i've taken a look and the file is there, and also it doesn't include any other files from within that js file... Is there something i need to do in the webview code? seems like there is code to recognise images in there, is there something i need to recognise javascript